# Aframe 'startEvents' not working with gltf model

Tags: javascript, html, aframe, virtual-reality

I'm trying to animate the position of a gltf model using A-Frame by clicking on a button. The animation works without the 'startEvents' property but stops working as soon as the property is added. The animation does work on an aframe primitive.

Here's an example of the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/ofp46ge0/1/

HTML:

```
<a-entity id="#whale" gltf-model="#whale" position="0 1.5 -10" rotation="5 -50 0" scale="5 5 5" 
animation="property: position; from: 0 1.5 -10; to: 0 0 0; startEvents: position; dur: 2000; delay: 2000;">
</a-entity>
```

JS:

```
document.querySelector(".enter").addEventListener('click',function () {
  document.querySelector("#whale").emit("position");
});
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an `<a-asset-item id="whale">` and your event is going there. Rename it to `id="whaleModel"`.

Comment: Ah, I was thinking it might be something very straightforward that I'm missing. Thank you!